# create link in ajax callback

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I create a link in ajax callback function and define a class for that, commands that I write on click of this link doesn't work. the code is here:

```
$('.catpics').click(function(){
   var id=$(this).attr('id');
   $.post('storehouse.php', {
     catid:id,
     btn:'showsub'
   },function(data){
     $('#subcatshelf').append('<a class="catpics" id="'+ data+'">'+data+'</a>');
   });
```

Comment: It doesn't work perhaps because you didn't include a `href=url` in your `<a>` tag so you're just getting some underlined text rather than a link, right?

Comment: what is important for me is that onclick function happens for my link too, I test it with href but doesn't work

Comment: The duplicate will explain how to add your events.  Basically you can bind to a parent element that contains the links, and just respond to all clicks like `$(".catpiccontainer").on('click','.catpics', function() {...});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.catpics').click(function(){` only binds to links once. You're looking for `.on` which will bind to the first object you give it (so you can give it the `body` of your webpage) and then tell it to listen for clicks on `.catpics` and since the listener is on the `body` and not the individual `.catpics` elements, it wont matter when the links are actually inserted or deleted:

```
$('body').on('click', '.catpics', function() {
   var id=$(this).attr('id');
   $.post('storehouse.php', {catid:id,btn:'showsub'},function(data){
     $('#subcatshelf').append('<a class="catpics" id="'+ data+'">'+data+'</a>');
   });
});
```

alternatively you can make click work just fine by pulling out the event handler and just setting up a new clicked listener as you insert a new link:

```
function clickedCatPic() {
   var id=$(this).attr('id');
   $.post('storehouse.php', {catid:id,btn:'showsub'},function(data){
     var link = $('<a class="catpics" id="'+ data+'">'+data+'</a>');
     $('#subcatshelf').append(link);
     link.click(clickedCatPic);
   });
}

$('.catpics').click(clickedCatPic);
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works